# How to read web application config file in unit test in another application

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I have one web application (say: WebApp). And another application as unit test application where I have written unit tests for WebApp.

Now I have a requirement to write test cases for some config sections. For this, I want to read the web.config file of WebApp.

How is this possible to do this, please advise.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On googling I have one way to make use of "webconfigurationmanager", but it requires a physical path of web.config file, which is not possible to provide.

Comment: you're attempting to write unit tests to parse XML configuration?  For what purpose?  Don't these config files change per environment?  If not, do they even belong in the config file?

Comment: Yes, these config files change per environment. Actually, I have to test for some keys, present in config or not. We have configs like web.config, web.dev.config, web.stage.config, web.prod.config. For all environments, I need to test.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't. Just copy and paste your .config in solution explorer from one project to the other.

Long answer, I think is technically possible, but it's not worth it. Also, things like the DB connection should be different for development and testing environments IMHO

Comment: My test project already has app.config in it. I have included web.config using "Add as a Link" to my test project, but still fail to read config using ConfigurationManager

Comment: This is really urgent and not getting any working solution for this